# How to fix "The message could not be processed" error on web service

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

Web service returns this error and I tried mostly everything but still couldn't fix it. I dont know if the problem is about the configuration..

> The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IGazlarOrtak/EkstreSorgulama' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

Here's my settings:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpoint" maxBufferPoolSize="2000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000" maxArrayLength="2000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
```

```
<endpoint address="https://webservice.halkbank.com.tr/EkstreWebServis.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpoint"
        contract="HalkbankWService.IGazlarOrtak" name="wsHttpEndpoint" />
```

Comment: Did you change the interface name after creating the WCF project? You can try right-clicking on the svc file -**View MarkUp**-and then modifying the Service.

Comment: @QIYou No, I didn't change anything.

Comment: I tried searching for a solution to this problem and usually can add a timeout to solve the problem. Add Code: **closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:10"**

Comment: @QIYou I really appreciate your effort for helping but still didn't effect anything.

Comment: I searched a lot of material and visited a lot of forums, and the usual solution to this problem is to increase the receive timeout and security context token. But you tried and none of them solved the problem, so we had to focus on the operation and configuration. Check that the actions in your message are correct and consistent with the actions of the service endpoints. Check that your client and server bindings match, and that they use the same security model and transport protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **establishSecurityContext="false"** under **Message**. This disables SCT negotiation and uses the credentials for each message directly.

```
 <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpEndpoint" maxBufferPoolSize="2000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000" maxArrayLength="2000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000"/>
              <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext=“false” />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: I tried that also but it didn't fix the problem..